# Anyway to bypass the error: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25

Tags: php, apache, email

I get the following error from my php scripts on certain wifi networks:

Message: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

I fully understand the error, and realise it's dependant on which internet connection I'm on and their SMTP/port 25 set up.

The thing is I'm backpacking around the world and never know what connection I'm going to be on, so ideally, if smtp isn't available on port 25, I just want my code to bypass it and carry on - not error on mail() - I don't care if it doesn't send the email - I just want my pages to load!

The best solution I have come up so far is to have php code like this and uncomment when needed:

```
//if (1==1) {
if (mail($to, $subject, $emailConfirmationHTML, $headers)) {
```

Is there anything else I can put in the php - or the apache set up to help me out?

Comment: `localhost` is the machine on which you're running Apache. It's not related to the network to which you're connected - or at least, it shouldn't be. You should check that your machine has a `hosts` entry for `localhost` mapping to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: That is only an E_WARNING level error, your page should still load fine. Maybe your problem is proper error handling.

Answer (score 0):

i think the simple solution would be to wrap the statement in a try catch block, handle the exception and carry on.
ideally though if you want to be able to send mail from anywhere, you should look around for a mail relay, do a google search for "MAIL RELAY" and you will see a number of services you can use.

Comment: You can not catch errors, you would need to convert them into an Exception first.

Comment: exactly, this does not work unfortunately:

  try {
   if (mail($to, $subject, $emailConfirmationHTML, $headers)) {
    $emailConfirmationResponseXML = "<sent>true</sent>";  
   } else {
    $emailConfirmationResponseXML = "<sent>failed</sent>";  
   }
  } catch (Exception $e) {
   $emailConfirmationResponseXML = "<sent>true</sent>";  
  }

Answer (score 0):

you can config your smtp server to listen on any ip addresses your system has.
in most cases sendmail is the choice.

this configuration in sendmail will help you:

## SMTP daemon options

O DaemonPortOptions=Port=smtp,Addr=0.0.0.0, Name=MTA

modify your /etc/mail/sendmail.cf (or wherever it is) and set the Addr in SMTP daemon options to 0.0.0.0

Regards,
MAGMAG

Comment: In this day and age, Sendmail is hardly the default choice any longer. Especially for merely configuring a local outgoing mail spool, something much simpler would be appropriate. If you want to recommend a full-blown production MTA for casual users, I would pick Postfix.